# HTMLUNit error while using in android

Tags: android, htmlunit

Hi I am simply trying to load a page using the sample code at htmlunit site which is:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
```

But I am always getting this error on the second line of the above code. I have the lib included. What can be the problem. I searched for almost 2 days but stuck on the same part. Please help.

```
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960): Exception while initializing JavaScript for the page
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method 'jsxGet_href' was not found for href property in com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSImportRule
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.ClassConfiguration.addProperty(ClassConfiguration.java:109)
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.parsePropertyElement(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:402)
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.parseClassElement(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:349)
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.buildUsageMap(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:299)
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:149)
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:239)
05-20 10:58:11.322: ERROR/JavaScriptEngine(960):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.init(JavaScriptEngine.java:179)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are running this code under Android?   Which version of the API?   Which version of HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the solution, but I know a bit more about the issue, now.

I created a trivial 'hello world' app with the following activity code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    try
    {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient( BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3 );
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled( false ) ;
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");

        tv.setText( page.asText().substring( 0, 50 ) );
    }
    catch( Throwable t )
    {
        tv.setText(t.getMessage());
    }

    setContentView(tv);
```

I added the following jars to Eclipse project:

```
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
htmlunit-2.8.jar
htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar
httpclient-4.0.1.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
httpmime-4.0.1.jar
nekohtml-1.9.14.jar
sac-1.3.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
junit-4.5.jar
```

(And I had to manually remove the License.txt file from the JUnit jar, or the project would not build.)

Then I tried running in the simulator using Android SDKs 2.2 and 2.3, and in both cases saw the same exception reported by the OP.   (And saw the exception message displayed in the simulator.)

Changing the browser version has no effect, nor does turning off Javascript.  The requested URL also does not matter, as the exception is thrown during setup of the WebClient.

The exception occurs at line 105 of `ClassConfiguration`:

```
info.setReadMethod(hostClass_.getMethod(GETTER_PREFIX + name, (Class []) null));
```

Tracing this with the debugger, I saw `hostClass_` go through a number of values (including `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.BoxObject` and `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Attr`) with no problems.  It's only when it gets to `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSImportRule` that the problems start.

Strangely, the method DOES exist:

```
public String jsxGet_href() {
    return getImportRule().getHref();
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the source to `java.lang.Class` that the SDK provides (I [found sources](https://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) for other parts of the SDK, but not the JRE), but stepping through the code blind, I could see quite a bit of activity inside `getMethod`, including calls to `Class.checkPublicMemberAccess`, `Class.getClassCache`, and `ClassCache.getAllPublicMethods`, the last of which throws the exception.

Without the JRE source it's hard to see exactly what is failing, but... I suspect some kind of jar incompatibily issue.   Perhaps the HtmlUnit jars should be recompiled with Android SDK?